# Почему в RecyclerView, после фильтра выводиться два текста в одном пункте не синхронно

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

С помощью `RecyclerView` вывожу два текста в одном item, но после фильтрации они выводятся асинхронно.

Причина, после фильтрации создается новый `ArrayList`, который заполняется данными, которые совпадают с теми, которые я вел в поиске. Таким образом заполняется первое поле, а второе заполняется по позиции, соответственно позиция после ввода меняется и второе поле уже не совпадает с первой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Адаптар

```
public class CheeseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CheeseAdapter.Holder> {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<String> mDefaultCheeses;
    private List<String> mDefaultCheeses2;
    private List<String> mFilteredCheeses;
    private List<String> mFilteredCheeses2;
    List<Integer> arrImage;

    public CheeseAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, String[] titleTab, String[] prichTab, List<Integer> arrImage) {
        mInflater = inflater;

        // получаю массив для первого пункта
        mDefaultCheeses = Arrays.asList(titleTab);
        mFilteredCheeses = mDefaultCheeses;

        // для второго
        mDefaultCheeses2 = Arrays.asList(prichTab);
        mFilteredCheeses2 = mDefaultCheeses2;

        // картинку
        this.arrImage=arrImage;
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new Holder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
        View itemView = holder.itemView;

        TextView title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cheeseName);
        TextView title2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
        ImageView personPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);

        // вставляем в первый TextView
        title.setText(mFilteredCheeses.get(position));
        // второй
        title2.setText(mFilteredCheeses2.get(position));
        // картинка
        personPhoto.setImageResource(arrImage.get(position));
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilteredCheeses.size();
    }

    public void filter(String query) {
        mFilteredCheeses = new ArrayList<>();
        // находит совпадения
        for (String cheese : mDefaultCheeses) {
            if(cheese.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
                // добавляет в ArrayList
                mFilteredCheeses.add(cheese);
            }
        }
        // обновляется список
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я пробовал, но там не разобрался как затем их отделить.

Comment: Например как вставить в фильтр поиск только по заголовкам

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить заголовки? Получить один заголовок можно если ввести persons.get(3).title, а как получить все заголовки? Если просто вести persons.title, не работает

Comment: Все заработало) Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

1. Не надо создавать новый объект списка. Очищайте старый и наполняйте его заново

   ```
   //mFilteredCheeses = new ArrayList<>();
   mFilteredCheeses.clear();
   //наполняем новыми данными
   ```
2. Вы заменяете данные только в одном списке, а второй список и массив картинок остаются неизменными.

Answer (score 0):

Из комментариев:

Чтобы все это работало, данные, передаваемые адаптеру должны быть связаны (например коллекция POJO-моделей,каждая из которых содержит и ID картинки и заголовок и значение по одному из пунктов), а не разделены, как у вас. В текущем виде решение будет костыльным и нерациональным.

Для организации фильтра получаете из моделей заголовки и сравниваете, оставляете те, в которых совпадает - получаете отфильтрованные связанные данные.

Чтобы получить только модели, в которых заголовки совпадают с условием, проходите по коллекции моделей в цикле:

```
for (Person user:persons) { 
     if ( user.title.equals("some")) {// действие при совпадении} ;
}
```

где Person - класс-модель.

Данный код отберет все заголовки, которые совпадают со словом "some" в коллекции persons