# Выделять элементы прочитанными

Tags: java, android, adapter

Есть список recyclerView с некоторыми значениями, при переходе на какой то из элемент `открывается` информация об этом элементе.
Как сделать так, чтобы после того открыл элемент, он в списке менял цвет.

```
public class TopStoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TopStoriesAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<Model> topStoriesList;
private Context context;


public TopStoriesAdapter(List<Model> topStoriesList, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.topStoriesList = topStoriesList;
}

@Override
public TopStoriesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new TopStoriesAdapter.ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final TopStoriesAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    viewHolder.storyTitle.setText(topStoriesList.get(i).getTitle());
    viewHolder.storyCreator.setText(topStoriesList.get(i).getBy());
    viewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, TopStoryDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", topStoriesList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return topStoriesList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.storyTitle)
    TextView storyTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.storyCreator)
    TextView storyCreator;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        storyTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.storyTitle);
        storyCreator = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.storyCreator);
        this.view = view;
    }
}
}
```

Нашёл аналогичный [пример](http://javadevblog.com/shared-preferences-v-android-sohranyaem-nastrojki.html), но не получается применить для своего адаптера.

Comment: Не нужно изменять вопрос, после того, когда на него получен ответ, иначе ответ теряет смысл и будет бесполезен для других с аналогичной проблемой. Если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его одельно

Comment: И кажется в другом вашем вопросе я вас предупеждал, что так и будет и как это решается

Comment: @pavlofff заголовок вопроса не менялся, просто потому как этот вопрос потребовал разделение на две подзадачи, пришлось его поменять. Если Вы считаете, что нужно отредактировать вопрос, для полученного ответа, с уже моей реализацей - без проблем, мне не сложно.

Comment: Вам не нужно менять ЭТОТ вопрос после того, как на него получен ответ. Задайте другой вопрос

Comment: @pavlofff вы серьезно? я вижу только часть ответа на мой вопрос. И если Вы будете более внимательными, то заметите, что здесь лучше изменить откорректировать вопрос, вместо того чтобы плодить аналогичные.

Comment: @pavlofff + обратите внимание на последний комментарий Юрия, "не видно попыток его применения" - а вы только что удалили мою "попытку", тем самым не дав развитие вопросу.

Comment: Дело в том, что это не форум, а Q&A, здесь вопрос не для помощи вам лично и каких то "развитий" с сопровожднием правок, а для решения одной конкретной проблемы. У вас была проблема - как выделить прочитанный элемент, вам предложили вариант. Все. Может предложат другие варианты, как выделить прочитаное. Теперь вы пишите о совсем другой проблеме - выделяется только один элемент. Это совсем другая проблема и на нее другие ответы, поэтому задавайте другой вопрос, а этому не требуется никакого "развития". Так же ознакомьтесь с правилами работы данного ресурса

Comment: Так же могу вам сразу сказать, что для решения вашей проблемы исользование преференсов - тупик, не тратьте на него время. Вам предложили в ответе рабочее решение - БД, модель и поле о прочтении, развивайте его. С преференсами это работать нормально не будет.

Comment: Возможность редактировать вопрос нужна для того, чтобы добавлять подробности, код, исправлять опечатки и т.п.  А полностью менять содержимое вопроса нельзя, даже если новый вопрос похож на старый. Проблема в том, что такая замена делает ответы неактуальными, а труд их авторов - бессмысленным.

Comment: Если вы получили здесь ответ и у вас возник новый вопрос — опубликуйте его отдельно. Можно дать там ссылку на этот вопрос для понимания контекста задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрим на задачу с другой стороны. В этом примере адаптера мы заводим массив `boolean` значений, при нажатии на элемент списка в массиве меняется значение на `true`. В методе `onBindViewHolder` в зависимости от `true/false` ставится задний фон с красным/прозрачным цветом.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.AdapterHolder>
{
    List<Model> names;
    boolean[] checked;
    int check_count = 0;

    public class AdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RelativeLayout tbrvitemroot;
        AdapterHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tbrvitemroot = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tbrvitemroot);
        }
    }

    RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Model> names){
        names = names;
        checked = new boolean[names.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public AdapterHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int p2)
    {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tbrvitem, viewGroup, false);
        AdapterHolder pvh = new AdapterHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterHolder holder, final int position)
    {
if(checked[position]) holder.tbrvitemroot.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
else holder.tbrvitemroot.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.tbrvitemroot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    checked[position] = true;
//тут логика перехода
                }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return names.size(); 
    }

}
```

Теперь, когда все разобрали, идём дальше. Так как необходимо показывать прочитанные при последующих запусках приложения, нам нужно заменить логику массива на логику сохраненных значений. Тут два варианта - либо БД, либо `Preferences`. Будем использовать второе, т.к. это проще и данных немного. Теперь подумаем в каком виде мы будем хранить данные.

```
Не прочитано - 0
Прочитано - 1
```

То есть, если всего элементов 10, а прочитаны 2-й, 5-й и 7-й, то в `Preferences` будет

```
0010010100
```

Да, именно так. Ведь мы храним не позиции, а индексы.
Теперь сама реализация

1) Перед созданием адаптера нужно получить данные

```
boolean[] checked;
SharedPreferences mSettings = getSharedPreferences("save_state", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (mSettings.contains("save"))
String saved_str = mSettings.getString("save", ""));
for(int x = 0; x<saved_str.length; x++){
String saved_char = saved_str.substring(x, x+1);
if(saved_char.equals("0")) checked[x] = false;
else checked[x] = true;
}
else checked = new boolean[ /*здесь длина массива*/ ];
```

2) Отправляем массив вместе с данными в адаптер

```
RecyclerViewAdapter rva = new RecyclerViewAdapter(names, checked);
rv.setAdapter(rva);
```

3) Адаптер

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.AdapterHolder>
{
List<Model> names;
boolean[] checked;
int check_count = 0;

public class AdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RelativeLayout tbrvitemroot;
    AdapterHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tbrvitemroot = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tbrvitemroot);
    }
}

RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Model> names){
    names = names;
    checked = new boolean[names.size()];
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public AdapterHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int p2)
{
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tbrvitem, viewGroup, false);
    AdapterHolder pvh = new AdapterHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterHolder holder, final int position)
{
if(checked[position])     holder.tbrvitemroot.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
else     holder.tbrvitemroot.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    holder.tbrvitemroot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
holder.tbrvitemroot. setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int x = 0; x<names.size(); x++){
String new_char = (checked[x]) ? "1" : "0";
sb.append(new_char);
}
               Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
        editor.putString("save", sb.toString(););
        editor.apply();
//тут логика перехода
            }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return names.size(); 
}

}
```

Здесь мы берём данные из `Preferences` (если их нет, то не берём), "расшифровываем" строку в массив булевых значений и отправляемых в адаптер. Логика красный/прозрачный осталась такой же, как в адаптере выше. При нажатии на элемент списка пришлось полностью обновлять строку и данные.

**Пару слов о переходе**

Все так грамотно получилось, что при обратном переходе на активность со списком ничего не потеряется. Вы можете вернуться или `Intent`-ом или `finish()`-ом, разница лишь в потере скролла в первом случае.

**Мораль: ДУМАЙ как адаптер**

Comment: Отличный ответ, но можно было бы добавить пример логики перехода для Shared Preference и уже в комментарии добавить что возможно реализовать и с БД.

Comment: Я уже добавляю ;) Ждите

Comment: @Morozov Содержимое вашего списка не меняется в процессе работы приложения (данные в список не добавляются\удалются)? Иначе весь этот алгоритм работать не будет. Например, в список добавился один элемент в первую позицию. В ваших преференсах сохранено, что первая позиция отмечена, но там будет уже другой элемент, который еще не открывали. [Аналогичная проблема](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/567642/177345). Для корректной работы с динамическими данными они должны быть связаны в структуре самих данных, а не по позициям, сохраненным отдельно. Через преференсы такое реализовать нереально костыльно

Comment: Я это знаю. Но ведь данные не динамичные. Наверное. В вопросе не указано, статичные они или динамичные

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно как-то идентифицировать каждый элемент данных. Например по ID.

Далее в момент, который вы считаете сменой статуса с "непрочитано" на "прочитано" вам надо куда-то как-то сохранить этот статус или сменить его.

Например вы можете записать в SharedPrefernce ID прочитанного элемента. А ещё лучше - если у вас всё хранится в БД и у модели есть поле "прочитано" которое вы измените. Ещё лучше - все данные хранятся на сервере и вы изменяете статус "прочитано" на сервере, после чего обновляете данные клиента.

Comment: Спасибо, но бд я не использую. Было бы супер как с SharedPreference провернуть, пока не очень смекнул)

Comment: @Morozov, при прочитывании запишите ID в преференсы. В onBindViewHolder проверьте есть ли для этого ID значение. Если да - смените цвет

Comment: @Morozov, `SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` далее Получаем `pref.contains("key)` пишем pref.edit().putString(idInString).apply()`. Я не знаю как ещё объяснить и что показать. Попробуйте отдельный вопрос задать....

Comment: обновил вопрос.Взгляните пожалуйста.

Comment: @Morozov, так я же вам написал почти весь нужный код. В вопросе же не видно попыток его применения... Вам надо по клику писать в преференсы и в onBindViewHolder проверять есть ли запись в преференсах и в зависимсоти от этого менять цвет.

Comment: С преференами, как вы редлагаете в ответе, будет запоминаться только один (последний) элемент, а делать для нескольких айтемов через префернсы будет слишком костыльно.