# Id в SharedPreference и его использование

Tags: java, android, adapter

Было решено записывать Id в SharedPreference  при клике в адаптере, чтобы после этого можно было его использовать:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, TopStoryDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", topStoriesList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
            context.startActivity(intent);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sharedPreferences.edit();
            ed.putInt("id", id);
            ed.apply();
        }
```

Где `SharedPreferences` - хранилище типа "ключ-значение". `ed.putInt("id", id);` - ключ срока "`id`", значение - значение переменной id.

**Задача**:

Сейчас пробую в самом ViewHolder'e добавить поле id, после чего сохранять значение viewholder.id что потом делать по нему проверку(if/else).

*P.S. Открыт для правок.*

Comment: Таим способом вы можете сохранить id только для одного пункта (последнего нажатого), а не для нескольких пунктов в списке. Уж не знаю, кем решено использовать преференсы, но для такой задачи правильно использовать БД.

Comment: @pavlofff с бд знаком заочно, пробую реализовать таким образом. Если же есть какой то хороший пример с использование бд для конкретной задачи, буду только рад.

Comment: Если не знакомы с БД - хороший способ познакомиться. Не знание ведь не причина лепить какие то костыли, игнорируя правильное решение. Вот [здесь писал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559151/177345) про схожую задачу (избранное). Механизм простейший - при клике пишем в БД в выделеное поле признак отметки, при чтении - проверяем это поле и соответственно действуем.

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sharedPreferences.edit();
            ed.putInt("id", id);
            ed.apply();
```

У тебя это происходит после того как ты вызвал новое активити. Первое, запись в sharedPreference - это относительно долгий процесс по сравнению с другими операциями. Во-вторых, у тебя уходит контекст на другое активити и он тупо не успевает записать и когда пытается, `context` уже пропал.
Тебе надо сделать новый класс типо SharePreferenceManager и заниматься им там, то есть сделать `Instance` и статическими методами типо `putReadStoryId(String id)` уже записывать туда, это позволит выполнять код в другом потоке. И я бы посоветовал записывать уже в другом активити, чтобы точно убедиться, что активити открылось.

Также просмотрите отлично написанный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594699/211117) здесь, возможно такой вариант вам подойдёт.

Answer (score 0):

```
Editor ed = sPref.edit();
ed.putInt("id", id);
ed.apply();
```

Comment: Спасибо только не понимаю немного, как записать этот id после к примеру на какой то из элементов списка. И разве для сохранения id в конце используется не commit вместо apply?

Comment: У вас у view в которую Вы хотите записать этот id можно получить context view.getContext(). Соответственно Вы можете получить доступ к  SharedPreferences таким образом sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(view.getContext()) и от туда достать данные sPref.getInt("id", -1)

Comment: в идеале по клику хотел бы записывать id.

Comment: Ну это тоже самое. Вы в Onclick можете сделать то что я выше написал

Comment: в onBindViewHolder данные кладут во view

Comment: Обновил вопрос, опять видимо что то не так делаю.

Comment: А зачем вы вообще пытаетесь записать id в preference. какая у вас логика связана с этим?

Comment: Логика в том, чтобы при клике по элементу списка я сохранял id, после чего смотрел есть для этого значения ID и если оно есть, то изменять цвет нажатого элемента.

Comment: А зачем тогда вообще его сохранять? Вы по клику получаете id элемента и сразу проверяете

Comment: можете пожалуйста показать как, а то у меня всё как испорченный телефон. или стоит обновить вопрос? Просто как я понял надо сохранять его при клике. а в onBindViewHolder получать значение, сравнивать с айдишником данных для данной ячейки и разукрашивать.